# Accessing and Modifying the Course Overview via the API

Tags: desire2learn, valence

Looking at the methods available to the Learning Environment, (http://docs.valence.desire2learn.com/http-routingtable.html#cap-Learning%20Environment) I didn't initially see any references that would allow the API to retrieve and/or modify the Course Overview within the Content module.

**Edit**

Of course after posting I immediately discovered the following methods:

```
/d2l/api/le/(version)/(orgUnitId)/overview [GET]
/d2l/api/le/(version)/(orgUnitId)/overview/attachment [GET]
```

The issue still remains where I do not see methods to MODIFY this information.

Am I missing something or was this functionality overlooked / excluded for some reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doesn't look like it is included. I played around with this call:

```
GET /d2l/api/le/(version)/(orgUnitId)/content/root/
```

Thinking it may be part of the content as a whole, but it doesn't seem to be.  When viewing through the browser, it loads the Overview in an AJAXy way, so looking at parameters I tried this:

```
GET /d2l/api/le/(version)/(orgUnitId)/content/modules/(moduleId)
```

And put in *Overview* as the module ID as that is what was being passed along in the AJAX call as the identifier, but that didn't work either.  Looks like Overview is completely separate from the content and not accessible through those API end points. And looking through the docs, I can see no other end point that looks like it would address your needs.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation.Hopefully, we can see some changes to this in the future,

Comment: This is correct; at this time, API callers cannot set the course content overview, or provide/upload a new file attachment for it.